# How to add custom HTTP headers to asmx call using SoapExtension in c#

Tags: asmx

I am trying to add a custom HTTP header to the asmx call by intercepting it using the `ProcessMessage` (SoapMessage message) by extending `SoapExtension` Class in c#.

The problem here is that all i have in `ProcessMessage()` is the `SoapMessage`, while i need to add a custom http header.

I tried doing this :

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("X-MyHeader", "xyz");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: define the followings : (1) doesn't work (2) custom http header

Comment: Hey, i mean to say that i need to pass X-MyHeader:xyz in the HTTP Header of the Outgoing Request. When i'm doing : HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("X-MyHeader", "xyz"); i do not get any errors, but i don't see the header in the outgoing request headers(i'm capturing it using Wireshark).

Comment: Can you post a little bit more of your code? How are you adding the extension? Is the handler correctly attached?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using the following steps:

1. Build an assembly using the class

   ```
   namespace HttpWebRequestTest {
       public class CustomHttpRequestCreator : IWebRequestCreate         
       public CustomHttpRequestCreator() { }
       public WebRequest Create(Uri uri) {
           HttpWebRequest webRequest = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HttpWebRequest),
                                       BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Public |
                                       BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                       null, new object[] { uri, null }, null) as HttpWebRequest;


           webRequest.Headers.Add("MyHeader:MyValue");
           return webRequest;
       }
      }
    }
   ```
2. Add the file to GAC and register in web.config

   ```
   <system.net>
    <webRequestModules>
     <remove prefix="http:"/>
     <remove prefix="https:"/>
     <add prefix="http:" type="HttpWebRequestTest.CustomHttpRequestCreator, HttpWebRequestTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2bc4ccb2cdedce53" />
     <add prefix="https:" type="HttpWebRequestTest.CustomHttpRequestCreator, HttpWebRequestTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2bc4ccb2cdedce53" />
    </webRequestModules>
   </system.net>
   ```